# Use HashMap<String, Runnable> to avoid duplicate method

Tags: lambda, java-8, hashmap

Greeting, I have some functions defined like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWeek", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAvgWeek(BigInteger id) {
    List<TimePeriodCalc> result = Calc.getWeek(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMonth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAvgMonth(BigInteger id) {
    List<TimePeriodCalc> result = Calc.getMonth(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And maybe getYear, getQuarter, getDate ....

Now I would like to combine them and add one parameter to tell me what I need to return.
The problem now is I have to define switch case statement which may make my code lengthy and unprofessional.
Is there anyway I can use Lambda expression like this case :

```
HashMap<String, Runnable> myMap = .... (declare and input some values)
myMap.put("executeA", () -> funA())
myMap.get("executeA")
```

Then my code would look like :

```
result = myMap.get("week"); 
//Or any kinds of assignment, the map does not have to return a list
```

or :

```
result = myMap.get("year");
```

and so on ...

Thank you.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Instead of using switch-case to choose the function to execute, I would like to simply do things like :
`result = myMap.get("week") //calculate the week average `



Or it can be any thing that use lambda expression or at least java-8 style. Thank you

Comment: What is `some params...`? This is important, since you probably need a `Map<String, Function<Something, List<TimePeriodCalc>>>`, but `Function` can only take a single parameter (and `BiFunction` can take two, but no more)

Comment: I only have one params `BigInteger building_id`

Comment: @KhaNguyễn This is a [valid question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566824), you didn't have to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `getWeek`, `getMonth` etc. methods all take the same single parameter (a `BigInteger`, according to your comment) you can create a `Map` mapping strings to `Function<BigInteger, List<TimePeriodCalc>>` and populate this map with static method references...

```
Map<String, Function<BigInteger, List<TimePeriodCalc>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("week", Calc::getWeek);
myMap.put("month", Calc::getMonth)
...
```

... and then get the proper function from the map and `apply` it in your generic method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAny", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAvgAny(String period, BigInteger id) {
    List<TimePeriodCalc> result = myMap.get(period).apply(id)
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

Concerning your comment: Java only has [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) for functions with one parameter, and [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) for two parameters, i.e. *x -> y* and *(x, y) -> z*. AFAIK functions or method references with more than two parameters are not possible. If you have to pass more than two parameters, you could, as a workaround, use a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), taking *no* parameters but accessing the variables in its scope. This, however, would require the `Map` to be defined within the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAny", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAvgAny(String period, BigInteger id, many other parameters) {    
    Map<String, Supplier<List<TimePeriodCalc>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("week",  () -> Calc.getWeek(id and many other parameters));
    ...
    List<TimePeriodCalc> result = myMap.get(period).get();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Or you might wrap the different parameters into an `Object[]` and pass that to the function:

```
Map<String, Function<Object[], List<TimePeriodCalc>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("week",  p -> Calc.getWeek((BigInteger) p[0], (Some) p[1], (Other) p[2], (Class) p[3]));
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAny", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAvgAny(String period, BigInteger id, many other parameters) {    
    Object[] params = new Object[] {id and  many other parameters};
    List<TimePeriodCalc> result = myMap.get(period).apply(params);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

As pointed out [by Holger in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007885/use-hashmapstring-runnable-to-avoid-duplicate-method/45008270?noredirect=1#comment76991906_45008270), you can also define your own interface providing a single function with more than two parameters and then create a `Map` of those, using a lambda to implement that method and mapping from those parameters to the function you want to call.

```
interface MyInterface {
    List<TimePeriodCalc> getResult(BigInteger id, some more stuff);
}

Map<String, MyInterface> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("week", (id, more, stuff) -> Calc.getweek(id, more, stuff));
...
List<TimePeriodCalc> test = myMap.get("week").getResult(id, more, stuff);
```

Comment: Hi Tobias, 
Thank for the answer, that solved my problem.
Btw, what if my function takes more that 2 parameters ? It can't be done using hash map ?

Comment: Of course, you can also create your own interface defining a function with the intended parameters.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Not sure why, but I actually thought you could not use `lambda` with more than two parameters.

Comment: Apart from creating your own functional interface as @Holger suggests (which is a nice option, btw), if by some reason you can't or don't want to do this, you can use a currified function, i.e. for a 3 arguments function of types `A`, `B` and `C` and return type `D`, you could have `Function<A, Function<B, Function<C, D>>> myFunction = a -> b -> c -> yourMethod(a, b, c)`, where `yourMethod` is a method that receives 3 args of types `A`, `B` and `C` and return an object of type `D`. The syntax is cumbersome, but allows for nice functional programming techniques